# In FME, I want to copy a .tab file, place it in a new folder called 'GDA94 Archive' and rename the file with a prefix 'GDA94_'

Tags: fme-form, gda2020

I am very new to FME.

As part of my GDA2020 process, I would like to copy a .tab file from its current location, add a prefix to it called 'GDA94_' and then place it into a new folder in the same location that is called 'GDA94 Archive'.

Eg, If I started with a file like this:
ASSET_Road.tab

Then in the same location, in a folder called 'GDA94 Archive', I would then create the file 'GDA94_ASSET_Road.tab' using a FME script.

I've tried using the 'BulkAttributeRenamer' but it keeps renaming the fields within the tab file instead of the name of the tab file itself. I've also tried using 'FileCopy'-Move and 'Directory and File Path Names' but can't figure out how to manage the different functions within them to get what I want to achieve.

For now, you can assume that the GDA94 Archive folder already exists in that location. (Although in the future I would like to find a way to automatically create that folder wherever there is a tab file within different folders and subfolders).

Comment: How is your Python? What version of FME are you using? Will this be used using a local license or deployed on FME Server?

Comment: Thanks! To answer your questions - I don't know how to use Python.  FME(r) 2021.0.2.0 (20210429 - Build 21321 - WIN64). Local license.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use the PythonCaller in FME to copy and rename files. My workflow is as follows:

1. Set up a "Creator" and feed that into a "FeatureReader" Transformer
2. Set the "Format" to "Directory and File Pathnames" and select the folder your data sits in.
3. If you run the workbench now you (with Feature Caching turned on), the output PATH will list all files in the directory you selected. If you look through it, you will see "**path_windows**" - which gives you the full path of the file in windows readable format, "**path_name**" - name of the file without extension and the "**path_extension**" - just the extension of the file. With all of these you can build a python script to do what you need.
4. Add a "PythonCaller" transformer and connect the PATH output to the input of this caller.
5. In the PythonCaller, change the "**Class or Function to Process**" from "**FeatureProcessor**" to "**processFeature**". Delete all text under the first pass, so from the second green text block dow. It should look like this:

[image]

6. Now you need to add the Python script. You need to tell your Python script what modules you need to run. Each Module grants you access to certain processes / tasks. To copy or move files, you need the "**os**" and "**shutil**" modules, both are installed by default with FME.
7. Copy the following script into the PythonCaller, you will need to set the Destination folder if it isnt going to be in the same folder your TAB file is being copied from. I have included notes (the # in the code to explain what is happening) See the code to copy below:

```py
#First import the modules you need
import os
import shutil
def processFeature(feature):

 # This if statement looks for a file extension, in your case tab, it will ignore anything not tab
 # You can change this to anything you need, including a file name using path_filename == 'thefilename'
    if feature.getAttribute('path_extension') == 'tab':
        # If it finds what you asked it, it will set the source location of the file to the path_windows location
        src = feature.getAttribute('path_windows')

        # It sets the destination folder to Archive, in the same directory the file is located within.
        # If you want to set a different location then dest_older = r"full path to the folder"
        # Make sure you include the r in front of the path i.e. r"C:\temp\archive"
        dest_folder = os.path.join (feature.getAttribute('path_directory_windows'), "Archive")

        # Next set the destination file name. Here we use the full path of the original file, then the new Archive folder
        # And finally set "GDA94_" prefixed to the original filename.
        dest = os.path.join (dest_folder,"GDA94_" + feature.getAttribute('path_filename'))

        # We need to check the destination folder exists...if it doesnt, then this if statement makes it

        if os.path.exists(dest_folder):
            pass
        else:
            os.mkdir(dest_folder)
        #You can print out the file paths if you need to check. These are written to the "Translation log"
        print (src)
        print (dest)
        # Using the shutil we can copy the files from the source to the destination. If you really happy with how this works,
        # You can change shutil.copy to shutil.move
        shutil.copy(src,dest)
        print ("Copied")
```

If you copy that into the transformer the #'s will turn green, making it easier to see.

You can also add this anywhere in your workbench, you dont need to use a creator, you can use the output from another transformer feeding into the FeatureReader.

**EDIT - UPDATING FOR ALL FILES**

If you are wanting to copy / move all files, the easiest way is to change the extension check to be everything. Simply change the first `if` statement to the one below.

`if feature.getAttribute('path_extension') != '':`

Basically this says, if the extension attribute is not empty, copy / move the files. This also eliminates the potential for errors if your folder already has a folder within it. This script will fail if there is a folder, it will not copy folders in its current state.

Comment: Hi Keagan. Thanks so much for that, I've performed the python caller and it has worked! - I have one question. With the line -----    if feature.getAttribute('path_extension') == 'tab':  ----- If I wanted to make it so it will do any file in that location, not just a .tab file, how would I edit it? Do I need to somehow say     if feature.getAttribute('path_extension') == 'tab' OR 'dat' OR 'ID' OR 'MAP' - I tried that but it errored.

Comment: @KeaganAllen -I realise now that when I said I only wanted to transform a .tab file, I didn't mention that a tab file comes with three other files (.map, .dat and .id). They're background files that all work together to use in Mapinfo, and is easy to forget to mention them. Is there a tweak to the python code you can recommend that will allow me to copy all 4 of those types instead of just .tab?

Comment: Updated to include all files. Another thing, if the folder contains other supplementary data...like csv's, excel files or text files. These will also be copied with the new prefix. If that isnt required, you could add the extensions types to a list and then use that. If that is needed, let me know and I can show you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a bit more digging, I managed to find out how to get the answer. So I've posted it here:

If you goto this link: It's raining TIFFs! File download and renaming questions-of-the-week from the FME Community.by The FME Evangelist.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyF7MEuBdK0
And watch from:  18:16 to 24:35

To recreate:

1. 18:16 READER: Add a reader which looks at the folder you want - When you add it, use the following Parameters - Path Filter = *, Recurse into Subfolders = No, Allowed Path Type = Any, Retrieve file properties = Yes. Put workflow Options as = Individual Feature Types
2. 19:57 WRITER: Add 'filecopy' - Don't list an output yet.
3. 21:45 add 'AttributeManager' in between the writer and reader, and in the parameters (flower button) add a new Output Attribute called 'filecopy_dest_filename' which you can select from the dropdown list. Then next to it, in the Attribute Value put in 'path_filename' which you can get from the black down arrow button and then the brown left pointing arrow, then with the same black down arrow, you choose 'file editor' and it'll show up in the text body as '@Value(path_filename'. you add the Prefix onto it so it will say 'GDA94_@Value(path_filename).
4. Run, and you can now put in the folder destination location.

Comment: Hmmm. Now that I've done that for one tab file, when I try to put in a new tab file it doesn't work, I guess because the attribute fields are all different. Might still need some help after all.